# Endless php mail loop

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, sendmail

I have a problem with an running script on my (VPS) php server. I have accidentally created an endless php mail() loop. (forgot to add one to $i). I believe it was something like this:

```
while($i<30){mail("me@gmail.com","Its me","Hi me!","Greetings"); }
```

I think i have terminated the script, but mails are still flooding my gmail-box. I tried deleting the file.php and restarting the server but after the restart emails started appearing again. I have ssh-access, but i do not have a clue how to stop emails from sending. Since i am not very good with command line access, can you provide some instructions?

Comment: Do you know what you're using to send emails with? I think the most common option on a Linux box would be Postfix; if so, you can see some simple usage here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-postfix-flush-mail-queue.html.

Comment: You can check what is running using `ps aux`. Once you found the culprit you can `kill` processes based on their pid. It's also possible that the mails are still in the queue. Check your mailserver's documentation for how to view and clear this.

Comment: Add `$i++` to the end of the loop.

Comment: In addition to my explanation: The full script was going to send about 30 mails to a group of classmates. I am now going to check what services are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with logging in using SSH. I entered (as PeeHaa said) `ps aux`. About 20 postfix-processes came up. At this point, i killed all those processes with the command `pkill -u postfix`. Then i removed all the emails from the Queue using the method from Charlie S (`postsuper -d ALL`).

The emails stopped flooding, thanks guys!

Comment: Right On  :)

Everyone's forgot a counter or made a typo on an operator before.

Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 4):

The script will self terminate based on the php.in time settings.  If it [for whatever reason doesn't], just edit your php.ini, and restart your server from the web host manager.

Chances are the email flood is just ......  leftovers still coming in.  lol  The server can send a lot of emails before the auto script timeout is hit